# Idiomatic F# - Simple Statistical Functions

Tags: f#, idioms

As part of a simple challenge I am to write a couple of simple statistical functions by scratch and I'm trying to write them in the most "idiomatic F#" way possible. I am fairly new to Functional Programming so I'm looking to learn how to create simple stuff from the start.

Here's what I have so far:

```
let mean (x : float list) : float =
    (List.sum x) / (float (List.length x))

let variance (x : float list) : float =
    x
    |> List.map (fun a -> pown (a - (mean x)) 2)
    |> mean

let stdDev =
    variance >> Math.Sqrt
```

I like how the `stdDev` function is defined using composition but I get the feeling there might be some prettier, more idiomatic way of defining the first two.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is perfectly fine and idiomatic.

Personally, I prefer one liners whenever possible. That way I can align the code to highlight similarities and differences between the functions. Patterns just jump at you that way.

```
let mean     x = (Seq.sum x) / (float (Seq.length x))
let variance x = let m = mean x
                 x |> Seq.map (fun a -> pown (a - m) 2) |> mean
let stdDev   x = x |> variance |> Math.Sqrt
```

I also prefer `seq` to `list` because they can be used with lists, arrays, sets or any other sequence.

```
do  [| 5. ; 6. ; 7. |] |> stdDev |> printfn "%A"
do  [  5. ; 6. ; 7.  ] |> stdDev |> printfn "%A"    
Set [  5. ; 6. ; 7.  ] |> stdDev |> printfn "%A"
seq [  5. ; 6. ; 7.  ] |> stdDev |> printfn "%A"        
seq {  5.   ..   7.  } |> stdDev |> printfn "%A"
```

In F# is better to avoid the `>>` composition operator and use the pipe `|>` instead.
There are many issues with composing functions like that. For instance the above code would not be possible (using different types like lists and arrays).

Answer (score 1):

One minor change that might be worth doing is to extract the `mean x` call from the body of the lambda function in your `variance` function. The F# compiler is likely not going to do this for you automatically and so you'd end up re-computing the mean again for every single element in the list:

```
let variance (x : float list) : float =
    let mx = mean x
    x
    |> List.map (fun a -> pown (a - mx) 2)
    |> mean
```

As AMieres mentioned in another reply, you could also consider using a different type than a list. List is nice and functional, but `Seq` will make the code work with any collection. Alternatively, `Array` might be a bit faster if you were computing with larger data.

Comment: Good call. I just ran both versions on `[ 1.0 .. 100000.0 ]` and got: `Real: 00:06:29.198, CPU: 00:00:43.546, GC gen0: 1, gen1: 0, gen2: 0` and `Real: 00:00:00.050, CPU: 00:00:00.031, GC gen0: 1, gen1: 1, gen2: 0`.

What would your suggestion be regarding choosing types? Use `Seq` for "generic" code and `List` & `Array` for more specific use cases? I have only used `Seq` before when dealing with lazily-evaluated sequences...

Answer (score 0):

The function composition operator is not as bad as its reputation, it just needs a little care not to run into [value restriction](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mulambda/2010/05/01/finer-points-of-f-value-restriction/), or one of the related issues. The eponymous error FS0030 says:

> Either make the arguments to 'stdDev' explicit or, if you do not
>   intend for it to be generic, add a type annotation.

We are also able to add a type annotation to keep the let-bound value more general than would be otherwise inferred.

```
let mean : seq<_> -> _ = 
    Seq.fold (fun (s, l) t -> s + t, l + 1) (0., 0) >> function
    | _, 0 -> failwith "empty collection"
    | s, l -> s / float l
let variance x = x |> Seq.map (x |> mean |> (-) >> fun a -> a * a) |> mean
let stdDev : seq<_> -> _ = variance >> sqrt
[5. ; 6. ; 7.] |> stdDev |> printfn "%A"    // prints 0.8164965809
{5.   ..   7.} |> stdDev |> printfn "%A"    // prints 0.8164965809
```

Without annotation, both `mean` and `stdDev` would not compile here  without being called down in the module because of value restriction. Even then, they are restricted to the first type they encounter that implements `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<'T>`.

The definition of `variance`, on the other hand, is not amenable to eta reduction, it does not suffer from these problems. Composition is used to combine two functions: subtract from the [partially applied](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/partial-application/) mean, and multiply a value by itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! A lot of helpful stuff here.

What is the point of keeping the let-bound value more general if `mean` must always take a `float` (I believe because of the operation `s / float l`)? 

Additionally, on the composed function we are actually performing `(mean(X) - x)^2`, right? I understand it doesn't really matter for this example but the order of operands is something I'm struggling with when it comes to pipes. Would the right way to ensure `(x - mean(X))` be something like `x |> Seq.map (x |> mean |> (~-) |> (+))`? This looks very confusing...

Comment: Ok. Never mind that first question. I realize now that you mean a more general type in the sense of `Seq` vs `List`\`Array` and that without it, the first structure that makes use of the function will actually define the type that function must accept.
In this case, is there any difference in using `seq<_> -> _` vs `seq<float> -> float`?

Comment: @tls Admittedly, the way the mapping of `variance` is written should not be considered as idiomatic; it is probably better expressed as `((-) (mean x) >> fun a -> a * a)`. If you know the type and you not intend it to be generic, you may specify it as well; it's just that `seq<float> -> float` is more to type.